# Do exist an injective function from $\mathbb{R}^5 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: functions, special-functions

Do exist an injective function from $\mathbb{R}^5 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^4$?

I think it is true, but I am unable to find a simple example... Please help me.

I think it should be something like $$ q:\mathbb{R}^5 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^4, \ q(x,y,z,k,l) = (f(x,y),\ f(y,z),\ f(z,k),\ f(k,l)); $$
where $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, an injective function, as I just read here about that: [Injective function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/197735/injective-function-from-mathbbr2-to-mathbbr)

Am I wrong?

If there exists a such function, please give me an example. Thank you very much!

Comment: Once you know an injective function $f$ from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$, you can just use $\Phi((x,y,z,k,l))=(f(x,y), z, k, l)$

Comment: There exists a bijection between $\mathbb R^5$ and $\mathbb R^4$, because these sets have the same cardinality (equal continuum).

Comment: It should be noted, there is no continuous injection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the injection from $\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ that you read about.  If that bijection is $m=f(x,y)$ you can take $(x,y,z,k,l) \to (m,z,k,l)$  The last three components just go along for the ride.