# Is $\mathbb R^2$ equipotent to $\mathbb R$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know that $\mathbb N^2$ is equipotent to $\mathbb N$ (By drawing zig-zag path to join all the points on xy-plane). Is this method available to prove $\mathbb R^2 $ equipotent to $\mathbb R$?

Comment: Are you asking if there is a bijection $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$?  Is that what $\cong$ means here?

Comment: Oh, please please please search the site before think your question has never been asked before. This particular one has been asked about a zillion times now.

Comment: @ JavaMan: Yes.

Comment: @Camilo: Define elementary. Basic cardinal arithmetics *is* elementary. Explicit maps were given too.

Comment: Well, to show an explicit bijection $f:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow \mathbb R$, cardinal arithmetic is not elementary if you're a freshman...

Comment: $\cong$ in what sense? Isomorphism, no, existence of a bijection yes. You must be careful with the context in which you use symbols.

Comment: @Camilo: Basic cardinal arithmetics are, and should be, covered in every intro course to set theory. For me that was first semester in the university.

Comment: @ncmathsadist: Isomorphism as additive groups? Yes. But the comments indicate this means equicardinality.

Comment: @Camilo: Cantor's proof about the equipotency of the line with the plane was probably one of the first results of cardinal arithmetics. It's hard to get more elementary than that.

Comment: @Asaf: In that case, yes. One must be careful in setting context.

Comment: @Asaf: One of the closing users has informed me that he would like to withdraw his close vote, since this question is asking about whether a specific technique works. Reopening sounds reasonable to me. Do you think the questions are sufficiently distinct?

Comment: @Zev: I recall that casting closing votes allows cast reopening votes as well... Going through a moderator seems a bit... excessive. :-) But yeah, I suppose I'd vote to reopen after this was pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

That method is not available to prove the equipotency of $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R^2$. The geometry is different. When the zigzag finishes a diagonal line in $\mathbb Z^2$, it can move over and do the next diagonal line.  But in $\mathbb R^2$ there is no "next" line.

In fact it turns out that there is no continuous bijection between $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R^2$.

For ideas that do work, see [Examples of bijective map from $\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183361/bijective-map-from-mathbbr3-rightarrow-mathbbr).