# Specify a bijection from [0,1] to (0,1].

Tags: elementary-set-theory

A) Specify a bijection from [0,1] to (0,1]. This shows that  |[0,1]|   =  |(0,1]|

B) The Cantor-Bernstein-Schroeder (CBS) theorem says that if there's an injection from A to B and an injection from B to A, then there's a bijection from A to B (ie, |A| = |B|). Use this to come to again show that   |[0;1]| = |(0;1]|

Comment: Relevant: [Examples of bijective map from $\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183361/examples-of-bijective-map-from-mathbbr3-rightarrow-mathbbr/183383#183383)

Answer (score 3):

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{n+1}{n+2},&\text{if $x$ has the form $\frac n{n+1}$ for $n\in\Bbb N$} \\
x,&\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$

That is, $f$ maps $0\to\frac12\to\frac23\to\frac34\to\ldots$ and  is the identity function elsewhere in $[0,1]$.

---

More generally, let $\{s_1, s_2, s_3, \ldots\}$ be any countably infinite subset of $(0,1]$ and then define $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 
s_1 & \text{if $x = 0$} \\
s_{i+1} & \text{ if $x = s_i$ for some $i$ } \\
x & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 1):

See the first page of http://www.math.montana.edu/~geyer/2008/fall/361/key3.pdf for an explicit construction of the bijection and some more.

---

Added, so that the answer is not depended on an external source.

A bijection $f\colon (0,1) \to \mathbb R$ is given in this text as:
$$f(x) =
  \begin{cases}
    2-\frac1x & \text{for }0<x<\frac12, \\
    \frac1{1-x}-2 & \text{for }\frac12\le x<1.
  \end{cases}
$$
The inverse is
$$f^{-1}(x)=
  \begin{cases}
    \frac1{2-y} & \text{for }y<0, \\
    1-\frac1{2+y} & \text{for }y\ge0.
  \end{cases}
$$

Comment: The bijection in the file you link to (and other similar maps) have nice additional property that it maps rational numbers to rational numbers and irrational numbers to irrational numbers.