# What truly are length, area and volume? And considerations about divergence in normed spaces

Tags: normed-spaces, infinity

All the "(?)" are parts when i'm not sure at all if what i'm saying is right or not, it's just my intuition.

---

**Part 1**

In $\mathbb{R}$, we can define the length of a segment.

In $\mathbb{R}^2$, the 'equivalent' would be (?) the area of a closed shape.

In $\mathbb{R}^3$, the 'equivalent' would be (?) the volume of a closed object.

How is that extended to $\mathbb{R}^n$ ?

More generally, can we define such a thing in any normed space, and how do we calculate it ? (if not, in which spaces can we ?)

---

**Part 2**

In $\mathbb{R}$, the length of a segment can only diverge if the $x$ coordinate diverges towards $-\infty$ or $+\infty$, therefore there are two ways to get to infinity (?)

In $\mathbb{R}^2$, the length of a segment can diverge if the $x$ **or** the $y$ coordinate diverges towards $-\infty$ or $+\infty$... Therefore there are infinitely many ways to get to infinity (?).

However, if we now look at $\mathbb{R}^3$, the length of a segment can diverge if the $x$ **or** the $y$ **or** the $z$ coordinate diverges towards $-\infty$ or $+\infty$... Therefore there are infinitely many ways to get to infinity too... But this time, there are also infinitely more ways to do that than we had in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (?) !

Therefore, how can we know the infinity of ways we have to make the length of a segment diverge in a normed space $\mathbb{K}$ ? Is it $\aleph_{\dim\mathbb{K}}$ for $\dim\mathbb{K}\geq2$? (just a totally wild guess)

(be aware, even though i've used $\aleph$ in the line right before, i know about **nothing** about the different kind of infinities, so please post detailed answers/comments or i'll be totally lost.)

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are discussing is the notion referred to as [measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_%28mathematics%29).  While there are different notions of measure, the one that is most commonly used is that of [Lebesgue measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure).  The $n$-dimensional volume of a set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be taken as the Lebesgue measure of that set.

In any Euclidean space, it is indeed as you say: a set can only have infinite measure if it is unbounded, which in a sense means that it "extends to infinity".

Those links should give you a place to start looking.  I hope that helps.

Also: the cardinality of directions of motion from a particular point in $\mathbb{R}^n$ will be $2$ if $n = 1$ and $\mathfrak c^{n-1} = \mathfrak c$ (the cardinality of real numbers) for any $n > 1$.

---

Addendum: note that it is not *always* possible to define an intuitive notion of "volume" in a normed space.  In particular, the space $\ell^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ of bounded real sequences is an infinite dimensional normed space in which our traditional notions of assigning sets finite volumes falls apart.

Comment: What are _directions of motion_ ?

Comment: The question "how many directions of motion are there" is a slightly more precise rendering of "how many ways are there to get to infinity".  For each "direction of motion", there is a unique ray emanating from that point "towards infinity".

Comment: How can we have $c^{n-1}=c$ with $n>1$ ?

Comment: See [this link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183361/examples-of-bijective-map-from-mathbbr3-rightarrow-mathbbr/183383#183383) for an example

Comment: To be sure, as we talk about the cardinality of "directions of motion", we're really referring to the cardinality of [$n-1$ dimensional projective space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_space).

Comment: One minor edition: not every (bounded) subset of $R^n$ is Lebesgue measurable (assuming ZFC).