# Definition of dimension

Tags: vector-spaces, definition

Let us consider Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$. We say it is $n$-dimensional because each vector in it is an $n$-tuple $(x_1,...,x_n)$. However, it is possible to represent this exact same space using only a single number by creating a bijection $\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ (e.g. [for $n=3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183361/examples-of-bijective-map-from-mathbbr3-rightarrow-mathbbr)). Therefore, by the conventional definition of *dimension*, we must conclude that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is in fact one-dimensional.

How do we resolve this? What is a rigorous definition of dimension?

This question was inspired by [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/875209/if-the-planck-length-exists-why-doesnt-it-follow-then-that-the-world-is-one-di).

Comment: Dimension of a vector space is defined in terms of *linear maps*. The claim that dimension is an invariant amounts to saying there is no *bijective linear map* between $\mathbb R^n$ and $\mathbb R^m$ when $n \neq m$. So in particular, any bijection between $\mathbb R^n$ and $\mathbb R$ cannot be linear.

Comment: A bijection between $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}$ can, for $n \neq 1$, not be linear. Thus the spaces are not isomorphic as vector spaces.

Comment: `"by the conventional definition of dimension"` - what definition do you mean?

Comment: Great! @DanielFischer and Dustan: is there a proof that such a bijection cannot be linear?

Comment: @MarcinŁoś that the dimension is the least number of coordinates required to represent any point within the space.

Comment: @ozo this is a general algebraic fact, since there are $n$ linearly independent vectors in $\Bbb R^n$, any linear bijection must map a basis to another basis, i.e the target set needs to be of the same size, but that would produce a bijection between the *finite* sets $\{1,2,3,\ldots, n\}$ and $\{1\}$ which is impossible when $n>1$.

Comment: The rank formula, for example. That shows that the kernel of every linear $T\colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ has dimension $\geqslant n-1$, so for $n > 1$, it cannot be injective. For $n = 0$, there is not even a non-linear bijection.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that [tag:dimension-theory] fits here. You're asking about the dimension of a vector space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can resolve this when you notice that any such bijection does not preserve the vector space structure of $\Bbb R^3$. In simpler words, it is not a linear transformation.

(Assuming the axiom of choice, you can find such bijection which preserves the additive structure, and therefore the structure of a vector space over $\Bbb Q$, but never as a vector space over $\Bbb R$.)

The point is that cardinality "shakes off" disregards the structure and only considers the underlying set. But dimension requires structure, so you can't just define the dimension of a set as a vector space or a topological space, without specifying the topology or the vector space structure as well.

What is true is that $\Bbb R$ can be endowed with a $3$-dimensional real vector space structure. But this structure is incompatible with the usual structure of $\Bbb R$ as an ordered field.

Comment: Thank you. You hit the nail on the head by highlighting the fact that cardinality shakes off structure. I was imagining the two spaces as being identical.

Answer (score 2):

For vector spaces, the definition of dimension is the number of vectors in a basis for the vector space.

A basis for a vector space V over a field $\mathbb{F}$ is a set of vectors such that every vector in V is a unique linear combination of the basis vectors. That is, $\{ v_1, ..., v_k \}$ is a basis when every vector $v \in V$ can be written uniquely as $v = a_1 v_1 + \dots + a_k v_k$ for scalars $a_1$, \dots, $a_k \in \mathbb{F}$.

It is possible to prove all bases for the same vector space have the same number of vectors, and this number is defined to be the dimension.

For $\mathbb{R}^n$, a basis is $(1,0,\dots,0)$, $(0,1,\dots,0)$, ..., $(0,0,\dots,1)$ so it has dimension $n$.