# Prove that scalar functions of vectors cannot be inverted

Tags: inverse

The following seems obvious to me (because information is clearly lost), but I have no idea how to prove it:

Suppose we have some arbitrary complex vector $\mathbf{A}$ with $m$ components. Let $f(\mathbf{A}):\mathbb{C}^{m}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$. Prove that there does not exist a function $f$ for which we can retrieve $\mathbf{A}$ from $f(\mathbf{A})$ unless $m=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is false.  Take a [bijection of $\mathbb{R}^m$ with $\mathbb{R}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183361/examples-of-bijective-map-from-mathbbr3-rightarrow-mathbbr?lq=1), and do this with both the real and complex components separately, to get a bijection between $\mathbb{C}^m$ and $\mathbb{C}$.

This is, of course, not linear -- there is no such linear $f$, by a simple dimensionality argument.

Comment: Indeed. I even already had that link favorited... Thanks!