# Is it possible to create a bijection between all pairs of reals and a real?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

The title basically says it all.  Is it possible to associate with each pair of reals, another unique real?  I guess you could say I'm looking for functions of two real arguments that return a distinct real number.

Comment: Recall that the reals are in bijection with $2^{\Bbb N}$ via dyadic fractions.

Comment: The accepted answer to [Examples of bijective map from $\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183361/examples-of-bijective-map-from-mathbbr3-rightarrow-mathbbr)  covers several ways to do so and does it very thoroughly.