# bijective function between $(0,1)$ and $(0,1)\times(0,1)$

Tags: functions

I know there exists one, but I want to find the explicit form of some bijective function between $(0,1)$ and $(0,1)\times(0,1)$.

Comment: Look here: http://wstein.org/edu/Spring2002/21b/handouts/Math21b3.pdf

By the way, would there be some function which construction (Or finding) does not rely on some power series expansions with some basis?

(I edit this since I´d said decimal expansions, and there are binary, too)

Comment: @LeviathanTheEsper Sure, you have all those that rely on binary expansion.

Comment: More seriously: [see this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183361/examples-of-bijective-map-from-mathbbr3-rightarrow-mathbbr?lq=1) (in particular for the detailed construction involving binary expansion, with the fun subtleties that arise), for the similar question of $[0,1]^2 \to [0,1]$.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks.

Comment: What is (0,1)x (0,1)?  A single point? A set of four elements?

Comment: @fleablood: $(0,1)\times(0,1):=\{(x,y)\mid 0<x<1,0<y<1\}\subset\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: Oh, for the love of... okay, I have *no* idea why the absolute obvious, clear, and straightforward meaning escaped me.  I got caught up on (0,1) being an ordered pair ... or being the set {0,1}.  D'oh!