# The usual bijection between $[0,1]$ and $[0,1]\times[0,1]$

Tags: cardinals

While trying to explain to someone else how you can have a bijection between $[0,1]$ and $[0,1]\times[0,1]$, I found an issue in the usual bijection that we use.

The usual bijection that I'm talking about is the one where $x=0.a_1a_2a_3a_4\ldots$ is sent on $(0.a_1a_3\ldots, 0.a_2a_4\ldots)$. First, I was wondering where is sent the real $1$. Then, I thought that since $1=0.999\ldots$, it is sent on $(0.999\ldots, 0.999\ldots)=(1,1)$.

However, this double-writing of a real number with a finite number of nonzero decimals leads to a non-injective map.

For example, the image of $0.1$ is $(0.1,0)$ whereas the image of $0.00\overline{90}$ is $(0.0\overline9,0)=(0.1,0)$ so the map is definitely not injective.

Is there something wrong with my comprehension of the bijection or there is an issue that people usually don't cover when talking about that bijection?

Note that I'm not doubting in any way that there is a bijection between $[0,1]$ and $[0,1]\times[0,1]$, I'm just wondering if the usual one is indeed a bijection.

Comment: If you use a particular representation of the real numbers to define a one-to-one map you have to take care that your representation is unique, otherwise you run into exactly the kind of trouble you are describing. (you not only have a problem with the map not being one-to-one, you also have to verify it's well defined...)

Comment: Indeed, is there a problem remaining here? "in the usual bijection that we use" Don't know what "usual" refers to here...

Comment: @Thomas But then, if you use a particular representation, some elements in $[0,1]^2$ won't have any preimage so the map will not be bijective

Comment: It’s an issue that is often ignored or hand-waved. [This answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/183383/12042) to an earlier question shows one way to fix the problem.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you very much :)

Comment: @H.Potter: My pleasure.