# Look for a one-to-one function that maps a square to R

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I am looking for a one-to-one function which maps (0,1)^2 to R. It is preferable that the function doesn't involve trig functions.
I have tried several mappings like $\ln(\frac{x_2}{1-x_1}),$ but they are not one-to-one. The challenge for me is the one-to-one requirement.

I have read [Examples of bijective map from $\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183361/examples-of-bijective-map-from-mathbbr3-rightarrow-mathbbr). I like the idea there, but I need to use this function to do further calculation, so it has to be in explicit form. Is it possible to find such a function?

I appreciate any ideas and comments.

Comment: What do you mean use this to do further calculation?  Any such function will be discontinuous because you are mixing dimensions.  I think the functions you find in the link are the best you will do.

Comment: Thank you @RossMillikan. Further calculation means summation/subtraction/derivative, etc. Did you mean there is no such functions can be continuous?

Answer (score 0):

Work with the decimal representation ( we take the finite one if there is ambiguity).

We map $(0.a_1a_2\dots,0.b_1b_2\dots )$ to $0.a_1b_1a_2b_2\dots$

I think this was Cantor's idea.

Comment: Thank you @Carry on Smiling. This is also the idea in the link I mentioned. I was just curious if there was other ways to avoid decimals.

Comment: @Piquito:  No, the first goes to $0.11231123\ldots$ and the second to $0.11321132\ldots$.  You need to worry about the terminating decimals, but all others work fine.

Comment: This does not have a point that maps to $0.09090909090909\ldots $

Comment: Oh God! I understood $a_ib_i$ as the product , not by the position. I apologize.

Comment: @RossMillikan: I think (0.00000....,0.99999......)=(0,1) applies. (See what says Carry in cases of ambiguity). Am I wrong?

Comment: @Piquito the problem is that the point I mentioned in $\Bbb R$ should go to $(0.0000\ldots, 0.99999\ldots)$ in $\Bbb R^2$, but we said to consider the terminating version in $\Bbb R^2$.  Meanwhile $(0.0000\ldots, 1.0000\ldots )$ goes to $1.00000\ldots$  In the answer linked by DEW this problem is solved, but it needs to be solved.

Comment: @RossMillikan: I understand. Thank you.