# Find a bijection between 2 intervals

Tags: real-analysis, functions

So I'm supposed to find a bijection between $[0,1) \longrightarrow [0,1]$. My attempt of solution is the function defined as

$$f(x):=\begin{cases}
2x, & \text{iff} \,\, x=\dfrac{1}{2^n} \\
x, &\text{otherwise} 
\end{cases}$$

Using this we have that if $x=\frac{1}{2}$, then $f(1/2)=1$ and so we got that covered. And for $x=\frac{1}{4}$ we have $f(1/4)=1/2$ and so on. Is this correct? Is it possible to assume that there is a bijection, when $n$ goes to infinity?

I also got another question: define a bijection from $[0,1) \longrightarrow [0,1) \times [0,1) \times \ \dots \ \times [0,1)$
$(n-$times$)$. My solution is just to define the value of $f(x)$ as a vector, i.e take $x \in [0,1)$ and $$f(x):=(x,x,x,\dots , x)$$ Is this correct?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'd say you're done, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first function you either compute the inverse, and show that is is the right and left inverse, or you should show that it is injective and surjective. (that is take to elements and show that they are mapped to different images, and show that ever element in $[0,1]$ has a pre-image)

The function is correct. But why you say assume there is a bijection? What do you mean by $n$ goes to infinity? You should take care that $f$ is well-defined which it is since $x= \frac{1}{2^n}$ is either true or false.

For the second function. Is $(0,\frac{1}{2}, \cdots, 0)$ in the image? You may also should say $n$-tuple instead of vector, since the codomain is not equipped with a vector space structure.

Comment: Thanks for the help! So when I have to prove that $f(x)$ is injective then I can split it up into two cases, when $x = \frac{1}{2^n}$ and when it is not, then just use that if $f(x)=f(y) \Longrightarrow x=y$. For showing that $f(x)$ is surjective then I choose $y \in [0,1]$, if $y$ is on the form $\frac{1}{2^k}$ then the pre image of $y$ has the form $x=\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}$. When $y$ is NOT on that form, then the inverse is just $x$. Am I correct? Also what I mean with $n$ tends to infinity is that it just "fills in the gap", but yea, I shouldn't use that.

Comment: Bonusquestion: Do you have any hints of how to prove the second question?

Comment: @ProShitposter Yes you are correct. The other way I mentioned is define a function $g \colon [0,1] \to [0,1) , x \mapsto \begin{cases} 1/2x & \text{if }x=1/2^n\\ x & \text{else.} \end{cases} $ and show that it is the inverse.

Comment: @ProShitposter For the other question you may want to modify this answer to the question: [Examples of bijective map from $\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/183383)

Answer (score 0):

The second function you defined is injective, not bijective, as it does not satisfy condition that each element of target set must be paired with at least one element of source set. This is obvious if you consider vector (x,x,x+1,x,...)