# Can a function from $(0,1)$ to $(0,1]$ be one-to-one and onto?

Tags: real-analysis

> Does there exist a function from $(0,1)$ to $(0,1]$ both one-to-one and onto, not necessarily continuous?

I couldn't think of any. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1965089/find-a-bijection-between-2-intervals, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160738/how-to-define-a-bijection-between-0-1-and-0-1

Answer (score 0):

Well, take the series $(\frac{1}{n})_{n\geq 1}$ and cut this series out of the set $(0,1] = (\frac{1}{n})_{n\geq 1} \cup A$, where the union is disjoint.

Then define the mapping $f:(0,1]\rightarrow (0,1)$ as follows:
$$f(x) =\left\{\begin{array}{ll} 
\frac{1}{n+1} & \mbox{if } x=\frac{1}{n}\\
x & \mbox{if } x\in A.
\end{array}
\right.$$
So the mapping maps the elements of $A$ to themselves, and the elements $1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4},\ldots$ to $\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{5},\ldots$.
This mapping is bijective.

Comment: Is this not the top answer [in the original](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160738/how-to-define-a-bijection-between-0-1-and-0-1)?

Comment: Indeed, it is. One can take an arbitrary infinite sequence starting with 1. This works not only when one wants to leave out a single element ...