# Existence of bijection between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R^2}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I would like to show the existence of a bijection between $(0,1)$ and $(0,1) \times (0,1)$. Would $f(x)=(x,x)$ work ($x \in (0,1)$)? It seems to be injective, but am I okay in using this even if its domain and range can go outside of $(0,1)$?

***Notes*:**

Define a second function $g: (0,1) \times (0,1) ↦ (0,1)$ which takes two decimal expansions $0.(x_1)(x_2)(x_3)...$ and $0.(y_1)(y_2)(y_3)...$, the first expansion coming from the first component of $(0,1) \times (0,1)$ and the second coming from the second component and maps them to $0.(x_1)(y_1)(x_2)(y_2)(x_3)(y_3)...$. For example, take $0.04265$ and **0.83169**. The function g maps the two decimal expansions to 0.0**8**4**3**2**1**6**6**5**9**. This seems like it could be an injective function because it takes two numbers and maps them to a unique number. However, I'm not sure how I would formally prove it...

This implies that, by Cantor-Schroder-Bernstein theorem, there exists a bijection between $(0,1)$ and $(0,1) \times (0,1)$.

Comment: This map is not surjective!

Comment: Fixed, thanks! The more important question is, can I use the function even though its domain/range technically can extend out beyond $(0,1)$?

Comment: Yes, it is ok. It is the restriction of the map $\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}^2$ defined by $x \mapsto (x,x)$, but it is a (well-defined) function anyway.

Comment: Note that $\text{dom }g = \{(x,x) : x \in (0,1)\} \neq (0,1)^2$, for example, $(\frac13,\frac12) \not\in \text{dom }g$.

Comment: If you want such a function, you can find it here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183361/examples-of-bijective-map-from-mathbbr3-rightarrow-mathbbr/183383#183383

Comment: @user8485, hold on, you define x to be in the interval $(0,1)$, and $12 ∉ (0,1)$, so I'm not really sure what you are getting at?

Comment: @Timor12 it was a typo, I already edited it.

Comment: @user8485, the domain of g is the unit square (without the borders), so ($\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2}$) seems to be in the domain. We can pick any point in the unit square and the output should be in the $(0,1)$ interval... Which changes my answer to $g(x,x)=x$, for $(x,x) \in (0,1)^2$.

Comment: What's $g(1/2, 1/4)$?

Comment: @Timor12 And how do you think we should define $g({1\over 3}, {1\over 2})$? Your function needs to be defined on **all of** $(0, 1)^2$, not just some of it.

Comment: @Timor12 I meant that you only defined $g$ for the points of the form $(x,x)$. We cannot calculate $g(\frac13,\frac12)$ using your definition.

Comment: To your suggestion of the different methods of finding a bijection, I think CBS is the most straightforward method, so I'll stick to that. Thanks though!

Comment: Two things:  Your function $g$ is **not** defined on $(0,1)^2$.  It's defined only on $\{ (x,y) \in (0,1) : x=y\}$.  Also, do you actually need to *construct* a bijection, or just show one exists?  CBS doesn't help you construct.

Comment: @NoahSchweber thanks, I got it. I'm now hard pressed to find a trivial injective function $(0,1)^2 → (0,1)$ function, though...

Comment: @tilper, sorry, I should've been more clear. I need to show the existence of a bijection.

Comment: @Timor12, what about $|\ln (xy)|$?  Haven't checked it myself but it's at least defined on $(0,1)^2$.

Comment: @tilper wouldn't work; counterexample: $g(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2})=\frac{1}{4}$ and $g(\frac{1}{3.8},  \frac{3.8}{4})=\frac{1}{4}$

Comment: @Timor12 There *isn't* a trivial injection - in particular, there is no *continuous* injection from $(0, 1)^2$ to $(0, 1)$. You're going to have to do some work.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, I think taking two decimal expansions and then mapping them to a different decimal expansion could work (see edited above), but I'm not sure how I would go about proving it formally. Intuition says it's an injective function, but I'd like to prove it. Any ideas?

Comment: @Timor12 You are starting to get the right idea, but it's going to be more complicated than what you've written. How do you deal with a number with an *infinite* decimal expansion - say, ${1\over 3}=0.333333...$ or ${1\over 7}=0.142857142857...$? What should $g({1\over 3}, {1\over 7})$ be? (There's a secondary difficulty, of how to deal with numbers with *two* decimal expansions - e.g. $0.2999999...=0.30000000....$ - but this can be handled fairly easily.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber, I see. If we have an irrational number as a first input, then the second input's decimal expansion would never start (theoretically) since it has an *infinite* expansion. I suppose I could make the output be of the form $0.(x_1)(y_1)(x_2)(y_2)(x_3)(y_3)...$ to avoid the problem.

Comment: @Timor12 **That** is a much better approach! (And note that it's not just irrationals that pose a problem - rationals whose denominator isn't a power of $10$, like ${1\over 3}$, also pose problems.) It needs a bit of work - what do you do if the input is a real with *two* decimal expansions? - but it's essentially the right map.

Comment: @NoahSchweber not sure what you are getting at... the $0.29999....$ expansion can be represented one way, namely by inputs $0.299999...$ and $0.9999...$. $0.3000000...$ does not have any two inputs (since $0.000000000...$ is not part of our domain), but that's okay because we are looking for an injective function, not a surjective function. The question is how do I argue formally, or is logic an argument enough?

Comment: @Timor12 I was thinking of $0.29999...$ as *one of* the two inputs we feed to $g$. That is, what should we do with $g(0.3, 0.4)=g(0.29999..., 0.399999)$? And no, this isn't formal enough - you need to show that $g$ is actually *well-defined*.  So you do need to say something about what you want $g$ to do when one or both of its inputs have multiple decimal expansions.

Comment: So let's get this straight: you mean $0.299...$ with 9s continuing on and on for infinity is equal to $0.3$? If we chose to represent $g(0.3, 0.4)=g(0.299..., 0.399...)$ as you suggested, then we wouldn't have a function because in that case, g(0.3,0.4) would be either 0.34 or 0.239999, and that violates the definition of a function.

Comment: @NoahSchweber To avoid this, I would define 0.2999 repeating and 0.3 as two distinct numbers, because if they were equal, $g$ wouldn't be a function.

Comment: @Timor12 Well, too bad - they *are* equal. You can't just change what a real number is. You need to fix *your function*, $g$, so that it is well-defined.

Comment: @NoahSchweber can I then define $0.2999...$ to always be represented as $0.3$, $0.3999...$ to be represented as $0.4$, and so on, or is that breaking the rules? Otherwise I don't really see how I can redefine my function to fit the parameters.

Comment: @Timor12 Well, $0.29999...$ **is** equal to $0.300000...$ - there's no need for you to "define" them to be equal since they already are. The issue, again, is *how are you defining $g$*: what should $g(0.29999..., 0.39999...)=g(0.3, 0.4)$ be? (HINT: you can *pick* a decimal representation . . . )

Comment: @NoahSchweber right, so whenever I see $0.299...$ I can say that it will be  always $0.3$ in my function, so $g(0.2999..., 0.39999...)=g(0.3, 0.4)=0.34$. That's what I meant, though probably worded it poorly.

Comment: @Timor12 Yup, that's it! *Always pick the finite decimal expansion, if there's a choice*. (Or make the other choice - the point is, specify how you're going to pick the decimal expansion to use.) Now, can you show that this is in fact an injection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you **sure** it's surjective? What gets sent to $({1\over 2}, {1\over 3})$?

EDIT: In the comments below the OP, we've hashed out the following injection from $(0, 1)^2$ to $(0, 1)$ (which, in conjunction with the "diagonal" injection $x\mapsto(x, x)$ given by the OP originally, will establish that $(0, 1)$ and $(0, 1)^2$ have the same cardinality via Cantor-Shroeder-Bernstein): let the *standard decimal expansion* of a real $r$ be the decimal expansion of $r$ if $r$ has only one decimal expansion, and otherwise the decimal expansion with only finitely many $9$s. So e.g. the standard decimal expansion of $\pi$ is $3.14159...$, and the standard decimal expansion of ${1\over 2}$ is $0.5$ rather than $0.499999...$. Then, if $r, s$ are real numbers in $(0, 1)$ with standard decimal expansions $$r=0.a_1a_2a_3...\quad s=0.b_1b_2b_3,$$ we let $$g(r, s)=0.a_1b_1a_2b_2a_3b_3...$$

We're not done: we still need to show that this is *injective*. It's usually harder to prove something if you think it's trivial, so: how could $g$ *not* be injective? Well, for instance, if we had two numbers $r$ and $s$ such that $g(r, s)=0.221999999...$ and two *other* numbers $r'$ and $s'$ such that $g(r', s')=0.22200000...$, then this would be a problem. So: can you see why this sort of issue *can't* happen?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! How about I invoke the Cantor-Schroder-Bernstein theorem and define two functions f and g? Then can I say that there exists a bijective function?

Comment: However, the main question is, can I use that function even though its domain/range can go beyond $(0,1)$?

Comment: @Timor12 You can define a function on a restricted domain: let $f: (0, 1)\rightarrow (0, 1)^2: x\mapsto (x, x)$. There's no obligation to always have a function be defined on the largest possible domain!

Comment: @Timor12 Re: your first comment, yes, and you have an $f$ going one way; the difficulty is finding a $g$ to go the other way.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich The author's original question was whether a given function provided a bijection between $(0, 1)$ and $(0, 1)^2$; this indeed answers it.

Comment: Wait, this issue cannot happen since one of the inputs is not in our domain, i.e. $0.19999999...=g(0.1999..., 0.999....)$ and we've established that by our function $0.999...=1$, which is not in our domain $(0,1)$. Thus, there are no two inputs for that one output $(0.2)$; in fact, in this case, there are 0 inputs for 1 output, implying that the function is not surjective, but injection still holds?

Comment: @Timor12 I've tweaked the example so it's relevant. The point is that reals in the domain *could* (in principle) yield failures of injectivity, and you need to argue that they don't.