# Let $f : M \rightarrow N$ where $M$ and $N$ are manifolds of dimension $n$ and $m$. How to prove M diffeomorph to N only if $m=n$

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

Let $f : M \rightarrow N$ where $M$ and $N$ are manifolds of dimension $n$ and $m$

I don't know how to prove properly that $f$ can be a diffeomorphism only if $m=n$.

I wanted to prove that $f$ can be bijective only if $m=n$ but that's not true. So I guess the "smooth" caracter has to play something here.

Comment: See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183361/examples-of-bijective-map-from-mathbbr3-rightarrow-mathbbr)

Comment: This is not true. $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ have the same cardinality and so there does indeed exist a bijection between these two sets.

Comment: You should have more constraints about $f$, otherwise your proposition is not true as @Oiler has provided an argument.

Comment: There is a setting in which $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$ are different. They are different as topological spaces: there is no homeomorphism from one space to another. The obstruction to this homeomorphism is that these topological spaces have different topological dimension.

Comment: I edited my question to be closer to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a consequnce of the famous from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain

Comment: You don't need something that complicated in the smooth setting. Diffeomorphisms induce isomorphisms on tangent spaces, from which the result follows immediately.