# Order preserving map $\mathbb R^2 \mapsto \mathbb R$

Tags: group-theory, elementary-set-theory, order-theory, real-numbers, well-orders

What would be an order preserving map $\mathbb R^2 \mapsto \mathbb R$ if $\mathbb R^2$ is arbitrarily ordered by x then y?

I saw the interleaving answers here: [Examples of bijective map from $\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183361/examples-of-bijective-map-from-mathbbr3-rightarrow-mathbbr?lq=1) but they don't mention order preserving.

Simply doing a linear transofrmation $w=5x+7y$ for example isn't order preserving because before $(1,1) < (2,0)$ but after $12 > 10$.

So what would be an order preserving map? Is interleaving order preserving?

Edit: By arbitrarily ordering $\mathbb R^2$ I mean using a comparer like this one:

```
(a,b)=>{  //a,b are Vector2
    let x = a.x - b.x;
    if (x != 0){
        return x;
    }
    return a.y - b.y;  // a tie with x is broken with y
}
```

So for example $(1,3) < (1,5) < (2,2)$

Another comparer is to set a known minimum point and then to compare distances from that point. My set of points is known to be "larger" than that minimum.

For example: [image]

I set my minimum to $(0,0)$ and then order all the other points relative to their distance from that point. So we'll get: blue(2,3) < red(6,2) < green(9,5) etc.

Comment: If you mean an injective order preserving map, there is no such map.

Comment: Even if $\mathbb R^2$ is arbitrarily ordered by x then y? @Crostul

Comment: "arbitrarily ordered by x then y" is not clear: what do you mean? I mean lexicographic order.

Comment: I added a code example, I think it's the best explanation. @Crostul

Comment: If there is an order on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ then that order map will act as the order preserving map.

Comment: Then doing a linear transformation on it with a monotone increasing function like I've shown should preserve that order, but it doesn't. @SivaKumar

Comment: How do you prove that linear transformation is a monotone function on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ with respective the order given.

Comment: It's a straight line equation. I also added another comparer in the question. @SivaKumar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ordering you seem to be defining on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is
$$
(a,x)<(b,y)\qquad\text{for}\qquad
(a<b) \text{ or } (a=b \text{ and }x<y)
$$
Suppose $f\colon\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ is an injective order preserving map. Set
$$
T_a=\{(a,x):x\in\mathbb{R}\},
\qquad
S_a=f(T_a)
$$
Thus the image of $f$ is the disjoint union of the sets $S_a$, for $a\in\mathbb{R}$; moreover, $a<b$ implies that $S_a<S_b$, in the sense that $r\in S_a$ and $s\in S_b$ implies $r<s$.

Note that each $S_a$ is bounded; for instance, from $(a-1,0)<(a,x)<(a+1,0)$, we get
$$
f(a-1,0)<f(a,x)<f(a+1,0)
$$
and so $f(a-1,0)$ is a lower bound for $S_a$, while $f(a+1,0)$ is an upper bound for $S_a$.

Therefore $S_a$ has a greatest lower bound $l_a$ and a least upper bound $u_a$. Note that the sets $S_a$ have neither a minimum nor a maximum, so $S_a\subseteq(l_a,u_a)$.

Can you now find a contradiction?

---

For other orders on $\mathbb{R}^2$, an injective order preserving map may exist or not. For instance, take a bijection $f\colon\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ and order $\mathbb{R}^2$ by
$$
\mathbf{x}<\mathbf{y} \text{ if and only if } f(\mathbf{x})<f(\mathbf{y})
$$
Then, by definition, $f$ is an order preserving map.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what is $f$, is it sets that are represented by $a$?

Comment: Also, what about the other ordering I made?

Comment: @kuhaku Not clear what you mean by that.

Comment: $S_0$ is bounded above (by $f(1,1)$ e.g.) does it have a supremum in $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Comment: I edited the question with an example about the distance ordering.

Comment: @kuhaku Does that define an order?

Comment: The contradiction is there's a bound on a set that has no bounds? And why do the distances not define an order? There are no points in the opposite direction, all the points are around the yellow vector, isn't this an order of radii from (0,0)?

Comment: @kuhaku What's larger between $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$? And no, the contradiction is not there, but in the fact that every open interval contains a rational number.

Comment: They're equal. ${}$

Comment: @kuhaku *Non sequitur*. In $\mathbb{R}^2$, $(1,2)\ne(2,1)$.

Comment: Must an order distinguish each element? Can't there be some leeway for equality?

Comment: @kuhaku That's called a preorder. But of course, if a set has a preorder that's not an order, there cannot be an order preserving injective map into an ordered set.

Comment: I see now, I wasn't looking for a full order but a partial order or preorder. Are there better maps from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R$ that achieve this?

Comment: @kuhaku Any order that divides $\mathbb{R}^2$ into “uncountable layers” like the lexicographic order I showed, will produce the same contradiction.

Comment: Even for a preorder or partial order?