# A special solution for a functional inequality from $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R} $ onto $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, inequality, functional-inequalities

Is there a **bijection** solution $\eta:\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (with an explicit formula, if it is possible)  for the inequality
$$\min\{x,y\}\leq \eta(x,y)\leq \max\{x,y\}\;\; ; \;\; x\neq y?$$

Comment: A bijection with explicit formula.... I'd say it's quite hopeless.

Comment: It probably should not be too difficult to show that such function *exists*, some construction base on transfinite induction seems like a natural approach. Writing down a specific function with these properties seems to be more difficult.

Comment: Perhaps it is worth mentioning that there are some posts on this site about an explicit bijection between $\mathbb R^2$ and $\mathbb R$. For example, [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183361/examples-of-bijective-map-from-mathbbr3-rightarrow-mathbbr) and perhaps also some of the posts [linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/183361). However, the additional condition on minimum and maximum makes this more complicated.

Comment: You have asked this question twice: why don't you delete one of the copies (the previous one, for instance)?

Comment: The old one is in the sense of set theoretic aspect