# Existence of two subsets of $\mathbb R$ with a certain property, undecidable in $ZF$?

Tags: set-theory, real-numbers, axiom-of-choice

Inspired by [Question # 2420627](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2420627/prove-that-there-is-a-bijection-mathbbr-times-mathbbr-rightarrow-mathbbr) "Prove that there is a bijection $f:\mathbb R\times \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ in the form of $f(x,y)=a(x)+b(y)$" and the  answer and comments by Thomas Andrews.

Proposition. There exist subsets $A, B$ of $\mathbb R,$ each  a bijective image of $\mathbb R,$ such that the function $g:A\times B\to \mathbb R,$ where $g(a,b)=a+b,$ is a bijection. That is, $\forall x\in \mathbb R\; \exists! (a,b)\in A\times B\;(x=a+b).$

In $ZFC$ this is easily proven. I suspect that in $ZF$ it may be undecidable (Assuming $Con (ZF)$ of course).

Any thoughts or references on this? Perhaps an example like $L(S),$ for some $S$ in a Forcing extension of $V,$ where $L(S)$ doe not satisfy the Proposition.

Comment: Note that forcing extensions *preserve* the axiom of choice, so that's not where to look. *Symmetric submodels of* forcing extensions can lack choice.

Comment: @Noah Schweber . If $S$ is not in the ground model then $L[S]$ may fail to satisfy $AC$. For example there are forcing extensions $V[G_1], V[G_2]$ where $\mathbb R^{V[G_1]}=\mathbb R^{V[G_2]}$  but $|\mathbb R|^{[V[G_1]}\ne |\mathbb R|^{V[G_1]}$ so $L[\mathbb R^{V[G_1]} \Vdash \neg AC.$

Comment: @NoahSchweber.Thanks for the edit

Comment: @bof. That was a typo of mine. I edited.

Comment: I do not know what notation you are using. Under the standard interpretation, $L[X]$ is always a model of choice.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo I meant $L(X)$ as in Kunen's  textbook . I always get that notation mixed up  with $L[X].$

Comment: @NoahSchweber. I made a notation error : $L(S)$, not $L[S]$.

Comment: @Andrés: If I recall correctly, Kunen actually uses the opposite notation in his new book. Which is just awful. I recall having made a similar comment to someone some time ago, and they whipped open the book and showed me that "they are only following Kunen". Maybe it was only about $L(\Bbb R)$, which was denoted by $L[R]$ (like Shelah sometimes does in his papers). But nonetheless, that was the notation used.

Comment: @AsafKaragila. I am using Kunen's "old" book, first edition. Thank you.