# Can the Cantor pairing function be modified to support real numbers?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was looking at the cantor pairing function here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function and am quite amazed as to how it works very well for pairing and unpairing natural numbers.

So far, my test on natural numbers `π(47, 32)` work flawlessly but I have another special use case where I would want to use real numbers instead, for example`π(6036.154879072251,  21288)`. Is there a way to modify the function to allow support for real numbers?

Comment: Please do not add irrelevant tags back to your question.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Noted. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The formula for the pairing function is given on that page.

$\pi(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}(x+y)(x+y+1) + y$

$\pi(0,1) =2$ and $\pi(-2,2) = 2$. So it already fails to be injective for $\mathbb{Z}^2$.

The are other ways to show that $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ are equipotent; it cannot be done by a simple algebraic formula like this..

Comment: To the proposer: A simple formula like the one for $\pi(x,y)$ is continuous but no bijection from $\Bbb R^2$ to $\Bbb R$ is continuous.

Comment: Thanks all for the responses.In this regard, can you propose a better alternative to pairing two real numbers?

Comment: @AbadiEferu [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/183361/4280) has some ideas. Or [here](https://planetmath.org/bijectionbetweenunitintervalandunitsquare) for squares and intervals. Or [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_of_the_continuum) has a more set theoretic approach. GIYF.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma, π(0,1)=2 is a valid pair but π(−2,2) isn't a valid pair since the pairing function is designed to work with only natural numbers. My aim is to know if the function can be modified or adjusted such that a positive real number pair π(0.567, 3) would yield a valid result on pairing and on unpairing.Thanks

Comment: @AbadiEferu as Daniel said, no, this cannot be done.

Comment: I think you mean equipotent rather than idempotent.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft quite right, so edited.