# $f:\mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^m$ If $n \ne m$ then f is not injective or surjective

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

The title may be confusing but i want to show that if $f:\mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^m$ $f \in C^1$ with $m<n$ then f is not injective and If $m>n$ f is not surjective.

If $f$ was a linear transformations things would be simpler, i tought about recouring to rank theorem but i don't know How, any hints?

Comment: $\mathbf{R}$ and $\mathbf{R}^2$ are equipotent, hence there exists a bijection between them. Did you want $f$ to be differentiable with differentiable inverse?

Comment: Any conditions on $f$, e.g., continuity?  If not, then all Euclidean spaces of dimension $\geq 1$ are pairwise *equipotent*, so there to exist bijections (which are both injective and surjective), just not continuous ones.

Comment: Sorry forgot to add $C^1$

Comment: Can you add this smoothness requirement to the question?

Comment: Edited It already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is required to be ${\cal C}^{1}$, then you assume $f(0) = 0$ (where each zero denotes the zero vector of the appropriate dimension) and use the Implicit Function Theorem, which says that $f$ at $0$ is locally equivalent to its linear part.  This will reduce the problem to your preferred context: linear transformations.

A nice statement and method of proof of the Implicit Function Theorem can be found in V. Arnol'd's *Ordinary Differential Equations* (use the latest edition).

Comment: Even continuity is enough, per invariance of domain.

Comment: Thanks! Will look for It

Comment: @NoahSchweber, true, but invariance of domain may or may not be beyond the asker's level.  A likely situation is that they haven't taken general topology yet, and were given the extra smoothness allowance on $f$ to enable using the results that require it.

Comment: Actually seen general topology, but can only use results from analysis, this aproach on implicit function is what i was looking for

Answer (score 4):

The statement you want is (without further hypotheses on $f$) **false** - this was observed by Cantor, and is similar to how there is a bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$. See for example the discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183361/examples-of-bijective-map-from-mathbbr3-rightarrow-mathbbr).

- As a quick explanation of why such a thing might be expected, consider the "interleaving" map $i:[0,1)^2\rightarrow [0,1)$ gotten by interleaving the **non-trailing-$9$s** decimal expansions of the inputs - e.g. $$i(0.101010..., 0.3333...)=0.13031303...$$ This isn't *quite* what you want, but it is a bijection. Now how different are $[0,1]$ *(which is what Cantor originally phrased his theorem about, if I recall correctly)*, $[0,1)$, and $\mathbb{R}$ really (that is, in terms of cardinality)?

Now, if you demand that $f$ be *continuous*, you do indeed get what you want (as a corollary of [**invariance of domain**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain)). But there are in fact bijections between $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $\mathbb{R}^n$ for all integers $m,n>1$.

Comment: Any references on this theorem? My analysis book omisses this i think

Comment: @DanielMoraes It should appear in any elementary set theory book, and I think it's in "little Rudin" too. I don't think it has a name, unfortunately. [This paper of Gouvea](http://vigo.ime.unicamp.br/MA327/AMM-March11_Cantor.pdf) may be of interest. (Incidentally, assuming the axiom of choice, *every* infinite set is in bijection with its square!)