# Is there bijection from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R^2$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

It is easy to show that there is bijection from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb N^2$, but is  there similar one for $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R^2$ ?

 This problem is equivalent to other one - "Is there function $f:\mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R$ that has inverse of the form $f^{-1}:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$?"

Thanks for all the help

Comment: What does it mean "countable over"?

Comment: What does "countable over $\mathbb R$" mean?  If you are thinking about vector spaces, then $\mathbb R^2$ has dimension $2$ over $\mathbb R$.

Comment: If you mean, “Is $\mathbb{R}^2$ bijectable with $\mathbb{R}$?” the answer is “yes”.

Comment: Note that while $\mathbb N$ is countable, and has the same cardinality as $\mathbb N \times \mathbb N$, $\mathbb R$ is **not** countable, but has the same cardinality as $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$, hence, $\exists$ a bijection between $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb R \times \mathbb R$..  Please see Arturo's comment immediately above.

Comment: regarding a bijective map from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R$, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183361/examples-of-bijective-map-from-mathbbr3-rightarrow-mathbbr)