# Invertible function mapping inputs to (0,1) with sum to 1 constraint

Tags: functions

I would like to map inputs to $(0, 1)$ with sum to one constraint. 
At first, I came up with softmax function, but it's not invertible.
Is there any function that map inputs to (0, 1) with sum to one constraint?

For example, Let $x_i,y_i \in \mathbb{R}$ and $(_1,_2,_3)=(_1,_2,_3)$, then $Σ_=1$ with  $0<_<1$.

I only consider a dimension of input is greater than 2.

Comment: What does "map inputs to (0,1) with sum to one constraint." mean?

Comment: If $f(x_1, x_2, x_3) = (y_1, y_2, y_3)$, then $\Sigma y_i = 1$ with $0 \lt y_i \lt 1$

Comment: And what are the inputs?  Any number of real numbers? Only finite collections of real numbers?  More broadly, please edit your post to include all the information you have in mind.

Comment: Worth noting:  unless I misunderstand, any single input must be mapped to $1$, yes?  So it could hardly be invertible.  Or are you excluding single inputs?

Comment: I'm sorry. I only consider a dimension of input is greater than 2

Comment: Well, there are bijections between $\mathbb R^3$ and the unit cube, or whatever, but they aren't pretty.  So, I'm not sure what you are hoping for...  For instance, most functions of the form you want would take, say, $f(x,x,x)=\left(\frac 13, \frac 13, \frac 13\right)$  and, of course, lose invertibility.

Comment: I'm sorry but would you elaborate why $f(x_1,x_2,x_3) = (\frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{3})$ leads to losing invertibility?

Comment: What I said was $f(x,x,x)=\left(\frac 13, \frac 13, \frac 13\right)$.  So if all three inputs coincide, so do all three outputs.  That's sensible, but it destroys invertibility.

Comment: Then, it could be possible if function does not take the same components? I mean, there exists $i, j$ such that $x_i \neq x_j$

Comment: As I said, there are set theoretic bijections between the relevant sets, but I'd expect them to be quite ugly and hard to implement.  Is that really the sort of thing you wanted?  Very far cry from something like softmax.

Comment: I'm sorry but i can't imagine what set theoretic bijections look like, so I don't know that it is what I want.. Thank you for the detailed answer.

Comment: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183361/examples-of-bijective-map-from-mathbbr3-rightarrow-mathbbr) is a construction of a bijection between $\mathbb R^3$ and $\mathbb R$.  That's what set theoretic bijections look like.