# A Function Of 3 Values Which Never Gives The Same Output For Different Numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functions, physics, graphing-functions

I am currently looking at graphs which describe the movement of an object through spacetime. The graphs would look quite similar to [Feynman Diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_diagram) which describe the movement of some subatomic particle through spacetime. However, as you can see on a graph (or at least the kind which I am using), there are only 2 axes - often labelled as $\ x$ and $\ y$ - that represent a 2D plane. However - the spacial axis, $\ x$, can only represent 1 dimension. Therefore I would have to find a way to compress 3 spacial dimensions into 1. I will call this function $\ R$ and it will take the form $\ R(x,y,z)$ where $\ x,y$ and $\ z$ represent the 3 spacial dimensions of our universe.

But what about the movement of an object through space? I will represent this as a matrix where the first column is a vector of the "starting position" of the object, and the second column is a vector of the ending position. With this known, let our object start at position $\ \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 4 \\ 3\end{bmatrix}$ and move to position $\ \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 5 \\ 7 \end{bmatrix}$ over some time, $\ t$. We can represent this motion in the format:
$$\ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 4 & 5 \\ 3 & 7 \end{bmatrix}$$
This matrix represents the movement of an object through space, but not through time. We can set $\ t $ to some value, lets say "1". So now we have the movement of an object through space and a measure of the time it takes. But how would we compress this matrix into two numbers that are inherently 1 dimensional. We can do this with our $\ R$ function, but what is the $\ R$ function?

I tried using Eulers Number, $\ e$ to find this, and I tried the magnitude of both vectors added together and then put into a $\ \sqrt{}$ function, but I can't figure out how I would have a function which, for every input $\ x, y$ and $\ z$, would always give a different output for each input. Similar to:
$$\ R(1,1,1) \neq R(1,1,1.000001) \neq R(1,1,1.000002)... $$

#### Does anyone know of a function which behaves like this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "I tried using Euler's number to find this"

Comment: Because $\ e$ is irrational, I figured that raising $\ e$ to the power of each number and then adding the numbers together would yield different results for each number, but after testing this, I was wrong.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for either something like the  [maps described here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/183361/81360) or a space-filling curve

Comment: @BenGrossmann after checking the question which you linked, I can clarify that it is indeed what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

There is no continuous injective map $\Bbb R^3\to \Bbb R$.
In fact, this already fails for $\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R$.
Assume $f\colon \Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R$ is continuous and injective.
Pick three points $p_1,p_2,p_3\in \Bbb R^3$ (or $\Bbb R^2$ or any $\Bbb R^n$ with $n>1$) where the indices are chosen so that $f(p_1)<f(p_2)<f(p_3)$.
Now in $\Bbb R^2$, chose any path from $p_1$ to $p_2$ that avoids $p_2$.
Then the image under $f$ of this path must begin at $f(p_1)$ and continuously move to $f(p_3)$ - without ever passing $f(p_2)$. This is impossible.