# How to prove $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$ is equipotent (i.e. there is a 1-1 map between the two) to $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis

How to prove $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$ is equipotent (i.e. there is a 1-1 map between the two) to $\mathbb{R}$?

The way to prove $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$ is equipotent to is to $\mathbb{N}$ is to construct a function of two independent variables and one dependent variable, e.g. $g(m,n)=(m+n)^2+n$, and prove that it is bijective.

How can we construct such a function for $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, or $\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{R}$?

It seems that we can use fractals to cover a two dimensional plane with a line. But what exactly are such fractals? And how can we write them with functional expression?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183361/examples-of-bijective-map-from-mathbbr3-rightarrow-mathbbr?lq=1.

Comment: I see it uses continued fractions, which I guess is similar to the idea of using fractal geometry. I will study the answer.