# Is there a bijective map from $[0,1]$ to the unit sphere?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, elementary-set-theory

Is there a bijective map from $[0,1]$ to the unit sphere, (or to all vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ with length $1$ about $(0,0,0)$), ideally with an even distribution such that $[0,0.5)$ or $]$, maps to half the volume of the sphere etc.

Comment: They have the same cardinality, so yes.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183361/examples-of-bijective-map-from-mathbbr3-rightarrow-mathbbr

Comment: There is even a Borel bijection.  If you normalize measures so that both the interval and the sphere have the same total measure, then there is a measure-preserving Borel bijection.