# Can non-homeomorphic topological manifolds be built over the same set?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, diffeomorphism

Let $(M,\mathfrak{X})$ be a smooth manifold, where $M$ is a topological manifold and $\mathfrak{X}$ a smooth structure on it.

It is commonly mentioned (in introductory resources on smooth manifolds) that there may exist a (finite or infinite) number of other smooth structures $\mathfrak{X}'$ on $M$ such that $(M,\mathfrak{X}')$ is not diffeomorphic to $(M,\mathfrak{X})$; and that in some special cases, some kind of uniqueness does hold (e.g. for the three-dimenional case, [cf. this M.O post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/296171/unique-smooth-structure-on-3-manifolds)).

I am wondering about the analogous question in the category of topological manifolds (i.e., about something analogous to the notion of "[exotic structures](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/exotic+smooth+structure)", but for topological manifolds).

Namely:

Let $(X,\mathfrak{T})$ be a topological manifold (where X is a set and $\mathfrak{T}$ is a topology on $X$ that makes it a topological manifold). In general, does there exist another topology $\mathfrak{T}'$ on $X$ such that $(X,\mathfrak{T}')$ is a topological manifold that is not homeomorphic to $(X,\mathfrak{T})$ ? If so, are there more restrictive situations where we still have uniqueness of the topological-manifold structure ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the only thing you're preserving is the set $X$, then you can biject it to the set of points in some other manifold and use that manifold's topology.

For example, suppose you start with $(\mathbb{R},\mathfrak{T})$ where $\mathfrak{T}$ is the standard topology on $\mathbb R$. Then set $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ to be your favorite bijection (perhaps as in [MJD's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/183383/26369) to [Examples of bijective map from $\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/183361/26369)).

If $\mathfrak{T}'$ is the standard topology on the plane $\mathbb R^2$, then we can turn it into a topology $\mathfrak{T}''$ on $\mathbb R$ by using the [forward image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_%28mathematics%29) under $f$:

$$\mathfrak{T}''=\left\{f[U]\mid U\in\mathfrak{T}'\right\}$$

Now $(\mathbb R,\mathfrak{T}'')$ (the plane encoded so the points are technically real numbers) is not homeomorphic to $(\mathbb R,\mathfrak{T})$ (the real line).

(Instead of the plane, I could have used another 1-d manifold like the circle, but I figured changing dimension would be more striking/make it clear how little "$X$ is the same" controls.)

Comment: As an additional remark, *all* manifolds of positive dimension have the same cardinality (that of the continuum), so if you fix bijections and use the method of this answer, there are as many topologies on $\mathbb{R}$ that result in pairwise non-homeomorphic manifolds as there are homeomorphism types of positive-dimensional manifolds (and those are also continuum many, if I recall correctly).

Comment: I see, of course. So in fact in general, if one wishes to study the non-homeomorphic topological spaces $(X,\mathfrak{T})$, with all $X$ having the carnality of the reals, and all different topologies $\mathfrak{T}$ on $X$, one could without loss of generality represent them as the topological spaces $(X_0,\mathfrak{T})$, where the $\mathfrak{T}$'s are all different possible topologies on $X_0$, and $X_0$ is some fixed set of that cardinality (e.g. $[0,1]$, $S^1$, $\mathbb{R}^n$,...) .