# Is there a bijective map from $[-1,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: real-analysis

I have seen [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183361/examples-of-bijective-map-from-mathbbr3-rightarrow-mathbbr?noredirect=1&lq=1) question already, and that's not what I'm asking. I would like to know if there is a bijective map between the interval $(-1,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$; ie, is there a function that will take a pair $(a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and give me a unique number in $(-1,1)$. I would also like to know if this is also possible for $[-1,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$. Thank you!

Comment: The answer to the question already gives a bijection $\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$. Invert it to get a bijection $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R^2$. Then find a bijection $(-1, 1) \to \mathbb R$ which is relatively easy and compose to finish.

Comment: In both cases the cardinalities are the same.

Comment: @ayeayemaung Thank you!