Is the inverse of an orthogonality-preserving bijection $V \to W$ orthogonality-preserving?
Let $V,W$ be finite-dimensional vector spaces of a field $F$ equipped with non-degenerate symmetric bilinear forms $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle_V$ and $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_W$. We call a map $f : V \to W$ orthogonality-preserving if
$$\forall v,w\in V: \langle v,w\rangle_V = 0 \implies \langle f(v), f(w)\rangle_W = 0.$$
Note that $f$ is not required to be linear.
I wonder if for a bijective orthogonality-preserving map also the direction $\Leftarrow$ is true.
For general orthogonality-preserving maps this property is clearly wrong, a counterexample is given by the all-zero function. But for bijective maps, I could not find a proof neither a counterexample so far.
Comment. I opened a new question for the situation $V \to V$, where the easy counterexample in the answer below is not possible.

If a mapping $f:V\to W$ is bijective then for every $w\in W$ there exists a unique $v \in V$ s.t. $w=fv$. Now assume that $\langle w, w' \rangle =0$; we can rewrite this as $\langle fv, fv' \rangle=0$. Since $f$ preserves orthogonality it follows that $\langle v, v' \rangle =0$. Since $v=f^{-1}w$ and $v'=f^{-1}w'$ we can write $$\langle w, w' \rangle =0⇒ \langle f^{-1}w,f^{-1}w'\rangle =0.$$

@AnneBauval just saying "its wrong" does not make it so.

@TedBlack Your conclusion $\langle fv, fv'\rangle = 0 \implies \langle v, v'\rangle = 0$ is not covered by the assumption on $f$.

@AnneBauval I sharpened the assumption to $V = W$ now.

Please don't significantly change your question after it has been answered in a way that makes the answer(s) no longer relevant. See e.g. this meta discussion and the linked posts there.

@anankElpis That "relevant answer" should rather have been a comment, to help the asker to improve their question, by an additional assumption preventing from such uninteresting exceptions.

@anankElpis o.k., I will revert the edit and open a new question. My reasoning was that I wanted the question to be interesting, without loopholes in border cases. Therefore in my perception, it was not a "significant change", but an improvement. In any case, you could just have asked for it without downvoting immediately. Please check if you are happy now and remove the downvote.

@anankElpis The new question is at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/5011672/61691 Please check.

@AnneBauval yes I produced a circular argument. Thank God I did not post this as an answer...

@AnneBauval no need for this. I want to keep on record that  I have posted an erroneous comment, happens to the best of us.

@TedBlack No need but better imo, to not distract and mislead future readers.

The answer is no.
Consider a bijective map $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$ with the standard inner products on $\mathbb R, \mathbb R^2$ such that $f(0)=(0, 0)$.

Do you have in mind what the map might look like?  I think there are examples using binary expansion so that $f$ need not be a space filling curve.

Here's a solution for constructing a bijection from $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/183361/65023.  Also, if $f(0)\neq (0,0)$ for this example, then simply redefine $f$: find $v$ such that $f(v)=(0,0)$, and set $f(v)=f(0)$ and $f(0)=(0,0)$.

This answer should rather have been a comment, to help the asker to improve their question, by an additional assumption preventing from such uninteresting exceptions.

Another example of math stack exchange running smoothly… not. The answer does not make any sense (even grammatically) and yet it was checked!

@AnneBauval Us mere mortals need a bit more information in the definition of a map.   So given $x \in \mathbb{R}$ what is $f(x)$?

@TedBlack I cannot see any grammatical mistake, and this answer provides a whole family of counterexamples: any (therefore not specified further) bijection $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^2$ which maps $0$ to $(0,0)$.

@AnneBauval let me ask a silly question if you don’t mind: how can a map from a vector space of lower dimension to a vector space of higher dimension be surjective?

@TedBlack Read the post carefully ("Note that $f$
is not required to be linear"), and follow (for instance, as there are many other such posts on MSE) the link in my previous comment. See also user65023's second comment above.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@AnneBauval the link you provided is a map from a higher to a lower dimensional Euclidean space. Also, yes obviously the map can be nonlinear, so let’s see an example of a surjective nonlinear map from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$. That’s what could have been provided in the “answer.”

Let us continue in chat, as you suggested.

@TedBlack Frankly, I find your tone a bit inappropriate. To be a bit offensive as well: Just cause you don't get it, doesn't render the answer wrong. As soon as the base field $F$ is infinite, the sets $F$ and $F^2$ have the same cardinality, which precisely means that there exists a bijection $F \to F^2$. Then there exists such a bijection with $0 \mapsto 0$, too, and any such bijection will be a counterexample.

@azimut answers have to be more than one line hints. In this example the answer has to include such details as (i) one example of how a a bijection would be defined (ii) one example how orthogonality is preserved given such a definition etc. By the way, I never said the answer was wrong. I just said it was too terse to be an answer.
